# TCP/IP communication using sockets

Tags: ip, nat, dhcp, tcp, arp

It might be a basic doubt .
When we fill up in the client source code in case of TCP socket communication , we fill up the socket address structure with the destination address of the server .

But when the packet is sent back to the client from server , how does the server know the client's IP adrress ?

In short who fills up the source ip and the source port in the IP packet of the sender so that the destination host sens back to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every IP header contains the source and destination IP address, and every TCP header contains the source and destination port.  The server knows the client IP address by inspecting the IP and TCP packet headers sent to it by the client.

The network stack in your operating system fills in the client/source address.  It's possible to set your own source port when you create a client socket, but most times its easier to let the operating system choose an unused "ephemeral" port for you.  If you don't specify your own source port when creating a client socket, the operating system will populate it in the TCP header for you.

Comment: Thanks..But my doubt is what component of the network stack i.e, which protocol populate the source ip address in the ip packet ? Is it ARP / DHCP /NAT ?

Comment: All of the above :-).  Various routing protocols and devices in lower layers of the TCP/IP or OSI stacks can modify the TCP or IP headers, but your client/source operating system will have to fill in the initial values so the packet can be started on its way to the server.